# Read in multiple txt documents and output to excel with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to read in multiple txt files across across an indefinite amount of subdirectories. In the txt files is a peice of text on a new line, which is actually formatted like a network share "\uisdff\uiefn"

I am trying to get the name of the top level folder, and then for each row in the subsequent text file, write each line individually into an excel sheet, alongside the folder name and the date.

This is what I have currently -

```
import openpyxl
import subprocess
import datetime
import os, time

directory='.'

path='Test.xlsx'


wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

sheet_obj =  wb_obj["Sheet1"]


cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = 1, column = 1) 

m_row = 2000




subfolders = [f.name for f in os.scandir(directory) if f.is_dir() ]  
for i in subfolders:
    subdirectory= directory+'\\'+ i
    for file in os.listdir(subdirectory):
        filename= subdirectory+"\\"+file
        file1= open(filename, "r")
        for i in range(1, m_row + 1): 
            for items in file1.readlines():


                unc_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 1)
                fol_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 2)
                date_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 3)



                unc_obj.value = items
                fol_obj.value = "TEST"
                date_obj = date



    wb_obj.save(writepath)
```

Im very new to python, so some pointers would be awesome! No matter what I try, its either writing the last line in the last file, write to line 2000(there is 2000 lines in total across all documents, but this will vary), or its only writing in a1.

My text files look like the following

```
\\hbi\jinkn
\\test\jnn
```

---

```
    test = []
    for items in file1.readlines():

        thisitem = items.replace(r'"\\', r"\\")
        more = thisitem.replace("  ,is an open share\"", "")


        unc_obj = more
        print(unc_obj)
        MKT_obj = "TEST"
        date_obj= str(datetime.datetime.now())
        row = [unc_obj.rstrip(), MKT_obj,date_obj]
        test.append(row)

    sheet_obj.append(test)                


    wb_obj.save(writepath)
```

I am now looking at using sheet.append. But getting an error in which it cant convert values to excel.

Comment: Remove `for i in range(1, m_row + 1):` and use [Worksheet.append](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=append#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append)

Comment: Can i use append to specify specific columns. So above, if I want  the above objects in say column 1, 4 and 7, is there a way to specify this using append?

Comment: ***"in say column 1, 4 and 7"***: Yes, your `seq` have to be: `['Column1', None, None, 'TEST', None, None, 'Column 7']`

Comment: ValueError: Cannot convert ('\\\\test\\fgfdg', 'TEST', '2019-11-08 11:28:10.606475') to Excel 
Getting this error on the first row :(

Comment: ***`('\\\\test\\fgfdg', 'TEST', '2019-11-08 11:28:10.606475')`***: I assume, this is your `items` object, [edit] your question and show how do you use it.

Comment: done.  I append to an array called test, and once the loop is finished im appending to the sheet. and then saving the workbook.

Comment: unc_obj = list(more).extend([MKT_obj, date_obj])
print(unc_obj)

is printing None.

Comment: Do `unc_obj = list(more) ; unc.obj.extend([MKT_obj, date_obj])` and `.append(unc_obj)`. You don't need `test`, you can `.append(...` inside `for ...`